# Lifecycle of module scope defined object in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a module

myService.ts

In that I have code

```
import * from '../utils/helpers'

const serviceBroker: MyBroker = new MyBroker();

function abc (a) {
   serviceBroker.doSomething();
...
}
```

My question is what is the lifecycle of the serviceBroker object? When is it created and destroyed. For a single process will there only ever be instance of it?

It seems like a simple question, but google hasn't been helpful today.

Thanks